# Initialize Vue app after Firebase auth state changed

Tags: firebase, vue.js, firebase-authentication, vuejs2, vuex

I have a bit of a conundrum in my Vue/vuex/vue-router + Firebase app. The bootstrap code is supposed to initialize Firebase, as well as the signed in user (if any) in Vuex:

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app', router, store, template: '<App/>', components: { App },
  beforeCreate() {
    firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig)
      // Because the code below is async, the app gets created before user is returned...
      .auth().onAuthStateChanged(user => {
        this.$store.commit('syncAuthUser', user) // this executes too late...
      })
  }
})
```

In my routes, I have

```js
{ path: '/home', name: 'Home', component: Home, meta: { requiresAuth: true } }
```

as well as

```js
router.beforeEach((to, from, next) => {
  let authUser = store.getters.authUser // this is not set just yet...

  if (to.matched.some(record => record.meta.requiresAuth)) {
    if (!authUser) {
      next('signin') // /home will always hit here...
    }
    next()
  }
  else {
    next()
  }
})
```

#### Problem

As mentioned in the comments, the app gets the authenticated user too late. So, when you go to `/home` while logged in, the app will run the `beforeEach`check in the routes... And the user instance will not be available just yet, so it will think that you are not logged in, *when in fact you are* (it's clear from my computed properties that are properly updated a few moments later).

#### Question

So, how do I change my code, so that the Vue app gets initialized only after Firebase returns the user and after that user is passed to the Vuex store? Plese let me know if I am doing something completely wrong.

#### Attempts

1. I tried the ["unsubscribe" approach](https://forum.vuejs.org/t/firebase-auth-and-vue-router/3086/3); however, its problem is that the `onAuthStateChanged` would only be triggered once. So, if I put my crucial `this.$store.commit('syncAuthUser', user)` there, then that code would only execute when the app is created, and not when the user logs out for example.
2. I also tried a better approach [here](https://forum.vuejs.org/t/vue-routes-firebase-auth-sync-problem/4470/2). I did work for me, but I felt bad wrapping `onAuthStateChanged` in another `Promise`, for sure there must be a better way; plus, it seems wrong to place the auth user initialization login in the routes file.

Comment: Hi, I also ran into this problem with Firebase. I use Angular, but had the same problem. In the end I figured the reliable way is to wait in the component for the user authentication. And yes, observables is the way to go here.

Answer (score 3):

The easiest way is to wait for the auth state before mounting your app:

```
const app = new Vue({
  router,
  store,
  render: h => h(App),
});

firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(user => {
  store.commit('authStateChanged', user);
  app.$mount('#app');
});
```

If you want to show a spinner before mount put it in `#app`:

```
<div id="app"><div class="loader">Loading...</div></div>
```

In fact it will make your actions cleaner and the app more reliable if you extract the auth state logic to a `authStateChanged` commit as above, and handle your route redirection here too. As this will handle if the auth state changes while you are on a route while `router.beforeEach` will check when you're going to one.

```
firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(user => {
  store.commit('auth/authStateChanged', user);

  const isAuthed = Boolean(user);
  const { meta } = router.history.current;

  if (isAuthed && meta.isPublicOnly) { // e.g. /login + /signup
    router.push('/dashboard');
  } else if (!isAuthed && meta.isPrivate) {
    router.push('/login');
  }

  app.$mount('#app');
});
```

**Note** that the first `router.beforeEach` callback happens before this, so you should ignore it until auth state has been determined. Since we handle the first redirection in `onAuthStateChanged` it doesn't matter.

```
state: {
  isInited: false,
  isAuthed: false,
},
mutations: {
  authStateChanged(state, user) {
    state.isAuthed = Boolean(user);
    state.isInited = true;
  }
}

router.beforeEach((to, from, next) => {
  const { isInited, isAuthed } = store.state.user;

  if (isInited) {
    if (!isAuthed && to.matched.some(record => record.meta.isPrivate)) {
      return next('/login');
    } else if (isAuthed && to.matched.some(record => record.meta.isPublicOnly)) {
      return next('/dashboard');
    }
  }

  next();
});
```

You could probably prevent the route loading at all until `isInited` is true alternatively.

Comment: What if your app does have a member and non member area for example, but share components. If not logged in it will endlessly return `null` and never load the app. There is no difference between not logged in and waiting for login success response.

Comment: Not sure what you mean, if you're not logged in `onAuthStateChanged` will still be called with `user` set to null, so your app will still load but with your store state saying the user is not authed?

Comment: `null` will alway be the initial emitted value of the observable, also when you are logging in. The observable emits a new value when it changes the state, but by then your app can already be mounted or not. Hope I made my question clear.

Comment: That is not the case though, if you're logged in the first callback will have the user object, I would guess it's your observable implementation

Comment: Ok, I was just wondering. I found it difficult to implement a high level autentication state for some of the components. For example: I ran a function when a component finished loading and I found myself with a timing issue. Sometimes it did get the user object and sometimes it just returned null so I had to wait in the component for the user object. It is an Angular app, but I struggled getting an abstract solution on a higher level, like in a service or something. Maybe with this input I can take a look if I find a better solution. Could be an Angular thing though now that I think of it.

Comment: Yeah just do a little experiment and put a `firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged` outside of angular or anything else and see what the callback has with a console.log. I have it working that way in multiple apps

Comment: is `app.$mount('#app');` called intentionally after **every** auth change?

Comment: It's been a while since I touched view but I believe it's the same as ReactDOM.render which is fine to call multiple times (it is equivalent of calling a render from the top of the tree and Vue will intelligently re-render only what is needed). That being said you could have a simple var to do it once since I think it's unnecessary i.e. `if (!mounted) { app.$mount(..); mounted = true }`

Answer (score 1):

### EXAMPLE

*./App.vue*

```
created: function() {
  auth.onAuthStateChanged(user => {

    this.$store.dispatch("SET_USER", user)

    user.getIdToken().then( token => {
      this.$store.dispatch("SET_TOKEN", token)
    })
}
```

./store.js (mutations)

```
export default {
  SET_USER(state, user) {
    state.authenticated = !!user
    state.user = {
      email: user ? user.email : null,
      displayName: user ? user.displayName : null,
      photoURL: user ? user.photoURL : null,
    }
  }
  SET_TOKEN(state, payload) {
    state.token = payload
  }
}
```

### OVERVIEW

**LifeCycle**

This example works using Vue's `created:` lifecycle hook. Within `created:` we use `auth.onAuthStateChanged` to spin up an event listener. Your app is now listening for auth changes from firebase.

```
auth.onAuthStateChanged(user => { ...listening for user objects... })
```

The `user` object is returned whenever Firebase notices an auth state change. Use its *properties* and *methods* for authentication and authorization.

*Property:* `user.emailVerfied`

*Method:* `user.getIdToken()`

### TL;DR

When using Firebase `onAuthStateChanged`, you must implement `Observable` and `Subscriptions` objects. An RxJS Observable is asynchronous like a `promise`, and it will help you *wait* for the auth response from Firebase.

See the **first** argument, `nextOrObserver` from the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/node/firebase.auth.Auth#onAuthStateChanged):

```
onAuthStateChanged(nextOrObserver, error, completed) returns function()
```

The Observable *design pattern*, (i.e., asynchronous, push, multicast) is documented [here](http://reactivex.io/rxjs/manual/overview.html#introduction).

Comment: Try to avoid too many links in your answers - if they die then your answer will become unclear.

Comment: [@jmwatts](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1945990/mjwatts) Good point, moved extra links to comments:
Two great examples of using Observables in Vue:

[Vue w/RxJS](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0Jo_Q8NYd3I)
[Vue w/vue-rx](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jC0tKU2S_Gg)